# How to save string from input to existing text JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

I have `html` page, on that page I have `input` and `button`

I want to save the string in `input` into **existing** file like 'text.txt`

this is my `html` code

```
<input id="sub" dir="ltr" type="text" placeholder="type something">
<button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()" class="main-btn">Subscribe</button>
```

and this is my `javascript` function

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        const fs = require('fs')
        let data = document.getElementById("sub").value + "\r\n";
        fs.writeFile('Output.txt', data, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
        })
    }
</script>
```

but it's not working

Comment: Is this running in a browser on on nodejs? You can't use this code in a browser.

Comment: @JScoobyCed how can I make something like that happen ? because I just want to deploy that in my host and save some text in my `index.html` directory

Comment: As @JScoobyCed already mentioned, you can't run this from within your browser. What you can do however, is deploy a backend service (e.g. NodeJS, SpringBoot application) which exposes a REST Endpoint that writes to your textfile when called. You then call that endpoint from your browser application.
I should mention that directly writing to your backend is not allowed for security reasons. Imagine every browser could just write to your server whatever it likes - or even change existing files. This would allow attackers to basically compromise your server for free.

Comment: @pascalpuetz tnx i got that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just access the Filesystem from your browser.
Your options depend on what you are trying to achieve.

### 1. Save a txt file on the users local filesystem

You can create a "downloadable" element directly from JS. Depending on the browser the user will be prompted to allow downloads and/or where to store the file. You cannot access the file afterwards.

```js
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
download("hello.txt","This is the content of my file :)");
```

*Source: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/javascript+download+text+as+txt+file*

### 2. Save data inside the browser so you can read/write whenever the users visits your website

The localstorage API can create small keyed objects (like 5-10 mb) on the user system. You can read/write anything to or from it that is serializable.

```js
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
const cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
localStorage.removeItem('myCat');
```

*Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage*

### 3. Save a file/data on your server

If you need the file on the server itself, you must create a backend with php, nodejs etc. Then you must implement an endpoint that accepts the data you want to save and inside nodejs you can import the "fs" and directly write files to it.

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const content = 'Some content!'

fs.writeFile('/Users/joe/test.txt', content, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
  //file written successfully
})
```

*Source: https://nodejs.dev/learn/writing-files-with-nodejs*